# Assigning a TProc inside a non-generic inline method leads to compiler error. Why?

Tags: generics, inline, anonymous-function, delphi-11-alexandria

When trying to assign `procedure begin end` to a `TProc` in the code below,
I get a compiler error:

> E2441 Inline function declared in interface section must not use local symbol '.TMyClass.DoesNotCompile$ActRec'

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMyClass = class
    procedure Compiles<T>; inline;
    procedure DoesNotCompile; inline;
  end;


implementation

procedure TMyClass.Compiles<T>;
var
  m: TProc;
begin
  m := procedure begin end; //<== works
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoesNotCompile;
var
  m: TProc;
begin
  m := procedure begin end; //<== compiler error
end;

end.
```

I would expect the generic and non-generic versions to behave in the same way. What is the difference, and: is it safe to use the generic version?

I'm using Delphi 11.1 Alexandria.

Comment: Does the generic version still work if it gets instantiated and used?

Comment: Yes. Checked with `m := procedure begin WriteLn('works'); end; m;` and calling `myClass.Compiles<string>`.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. I would say to file a bug report, but [their bug system is down](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/embarcadero-quality-portal-migration/) right now. So contact [Embarcadero Support](https://www.embarcadero.com/support) and have them raise the bug internally.